# Parent Window opens new window with AJAX request in it and user cannot navigate in parent window unless AJAX finished

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have this web app which takes care of sync email with GMAIL.
I would like to launch the sync process in a new window to avoid users to switch page interrupting the syncing process. The other important thing is that during the synchronization process (considering  it could take several minutes) the user can work on different pages.

So every 5 minutes from the last synchronization the web app opens a new window with an url which launches the syncronization process with a progress bar. The synchronization process is made with an AJAX call.
Till here everything works fine except for the fact that in the parent window the user cannot navigate through pages unless the AJAX synchronization process in the new window hasn't finished.

It's like the parent and the new window are still connected and I don't want absolutely that.

Comment: in ajax did you async : false;

Comment: In the AJAX call async param is set to true.

Comment: Oh, It should be True check this link http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: It's already set to TRUE...